# Problems with display grid in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm try to display grid of buttons 5x5 programmatically in Android. But it doesn't display all of grid

XML code:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainTableLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>
```

Java code:

```
LinearLayout mainTable = findViewById(R.id.mainTableLayout);

    for(int i = 0; i < COUNT_COLUMS; i++) {

        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        for (int j = 0; j < COUNT_COLUMS; j++) {
            Button button = new Button(this);
            linearLayout.addView(button);
        }

        mainTable.addView(linearLayout);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work :

```
LinearLayout mainTable = findViewById(R.id.mainTableLayout);

    DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int DeviceTotalWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
    int with = DeviceTotalWidth / 5;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this);
        row.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        row.getWeightSum();
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            Button btnTag = new Button(this);
            btnTag.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(with, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            btnTag.setText("" + (j + 1 + (i * 5)));
            btnTag.setId(j + 1 + (i * 5));
            row.addView(btnTag);
        }

        mainTable.addView(row);
    }
```

But the better way is to use `GridLayout` !

Answer (score 0):

You can use RecyclerView instead of programmatically adding button in linearlayout. Use RecyclerView of GridLayoutManager with span count 5 & orientation vertical.